# 2 Column Editor quilljs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using ReactQuill text Editor. I need 2 column editor when my fist column fill then text moves to second column. I want to add a button in the editor toolbar which divide my one column layout to a two-column layout.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have checked the [React-Quill](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill#custom-editing-area) documentation it clearly mentions that you can have custom editing area and custom toolbar. Have you implemented or tried something by yourself. We can help you with the code if you have already tried something by yourself and it is not working

Comment: Please have you got an answer for this? @soheb

Comment: Are you still looking for the answer?

Comment: yes,i'm still loooking for this if you can help @Soheb

Comment: Hi, sorry for a delay response not much of Stack overflow user, https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill#custom-editing-area you can follow the link I have mentioned or if you can create a sandbox or something I can help you

Comment: https://codepen.io/elwazer007/pen/mdBMppX here's a playground for the quill , btw i don't use react-quill library but i believe that anything that can be done with it , will be easily with just quill itself @Soheb